# Eclipse Choose Initial Project Contents Error

Tags: eclipse, force.com-ide

I just got a new laptop and trying to get Eclipse up and running again.  When I go to create a new project and enter my credentials and click Next, it says fetching and then I get this screen.  Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Try manually putting in a package.xml and reload your project contents from the server. This may fix itself. Also, file an issue against the open source project for Force.com IDE. https://github.com/forcedotcom/idecore/issues

Comment: If I just click Finish, it downloads what is normally the first radial button, Classes, Components, Pages, Static Resources and Triggers.  I tried to create another project and same issue.

Comment: Is that a limitation of Eclipse itself? Or something in the plugin? Please still file the issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

This has something to do with large fonts and the UI for that dialog not dynamically sizing.

You can do two things (for now):
1) maximize that window
2) reduce your font size

Answer (score 0):

Can you please share the Eclipse, Force.com IDE and Java version using on your machine.

If you are using the Windows OS, then try with the following combinations: Eclipse Version Juno , Force.com IDE Version 33.0, Java Version 8.

If you are using MAC then Try Eclipse Version Kepler.